# Can we pass a varchar/text datatype in to a variable in pgbench?

Tags: postgresql

**--pgbench sql script**

```
[pg93@db1 load_test]$ cat get_email.sql 
\setrandom cnt 1 100000
\set v_username 'user_' || :cnt

begin;
select get_user_email(:v_username);
end;
```

get_user_email() is a function which can get user's email.

**--pgbench**

```
[pg93@db1 load_test]$ nohup pgbench -c 4 -T 10 -d proxy -U proxy  -N -n -f get_email.sql  >  get_email.out  2>&1 &
```

**--the get_email.out file says**

```
nohup: ignoring input
client 0 executing \setrandom cnt 1 100000
client 0 executing \set v_username 'user_' || :cnt
invalid input syntax for integer: "'user_'"
invalid input syntax for integer: "'user_'"
set: unsupported operator ||
```

It's seem that can only use integer datatype.

**--data**

```
db2=> select * from users limit 3;
 username |      email      
----------+-----------------
 user_6   | user_6@163.com
 user_19  | user_19@163.com
 user_20  | user_20@163.com
```

get_user_email() is a function which can get user's email.

Comment: Try simply `\set v_username 'user_' :cnt`.  This is no SQL operation, so the `||` operator does not work.

Comment: It's of no use , also get the same result "invalid input syntax for integer: "'user_'""

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, pgbench variables are supposed to be boolean, integer, float, or variable-references.

However it appears to be possible to pass arbitrary text to `--define` so long as you don't try to use pgbench operators that will treat it as a numeric value.

`pgbench` doesn't support `psql`-style `:'quoted_variable'` syntax for literals or `:"quoted_variable"` for identifiers. So you have to *quote the value you pass*.

e.g. if you invoke `pgbench` with `--define "v_username='fred'"` then the variable's string value will be `'fred'`, including the quotes. You can then write:

```
\setrandom cnt 1 100000

begin;
select get_user_email('user_' || :v_username);
end;
```

Note that the concatenation is done in SQL, as pgbench expression language doesn't have string operators.